# How to synchronize my mercurial projects before suspending and just after resuming

Tags: mercurial, commit, suspend

I've tried by including the corresponding `hg` commands in the `/etc/pm/sleep.d/00_update` file, in the cases of `hibernate|suspend)` and `thaw|resume)`, but there seems to be problems, as the wifi connection shuts down before the commit is done (and, yes, `00_uptdate` was the first to be executed). Is there any other strategy to keep projects synchronized by just sending the system to sleep before leaving the workplace? I mean automatically, of course a script with the `hg push` and `pm-suspend` would make it.